# Finding corresponding has_one row in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-one

If a job has_one cv associated with it:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :cv
end
```

I've set the routes up as follows:

```
  resources :jobs do
    resource :cv
  end
```

When I want to create a CV for a job I following the following link:

```
  <%= link_to "Add CV", new_job_cvs_path(j) %>
```

Which is associated with the following method in the CV controller:

```
  def new
    @job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
    @job_cv = @job.cv.new
  end
```

However this results in me getting the following error, for the @job_cv line:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: cvs.job_id: SELECT "cvs".* FROM "cvs" WHERE "cvs"."job_id" = ? LIMIT 1
```

I think I've set something up wrong somewhere, I just don't know where yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to create a migration for your new relationship, create new migration by

```
rails g migration AddCvToJobs
```

Then edit the newly created migration file in `app/db/migrate/xxx_add_cv_to_jobs.rb`:

```
class AddCvToJobs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :cvs, :job_id, :integer, index: true
  end
end
```

Then run `rake db:migrate` and try again.

Comment: Sorry, actually I've just tried it now and it gives me an rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `to_sym' for {:index=>true}

Comment: @user3295209 sorry I missed the column data type in migration file. I've updated the answer, change your migration and run migrate again :)

Comment: Yeah sorry, was away from computer.